# Why does StringRegExp slower when I add ^ to the pattern?

Tags: regex, performance, autoit, pcre

I have a `Measure` function which executes the pattern multiple times to get the average execution time.

```
Func Measure($text, $pattern, $repetitionCount)
    Local $timer, $elapsed = 0
    For $i = 1 To $repetitionCount
        $timer = TimerInit()
        StringRegExp($text, $pattern, 3)
        $elapsed += TimerDiff($timer)
    Next
    Return $elapsed
EndFunc
```

[This is the subject string](http://pastebin.com/n9d5EsQx). My first pattern is `(?m)^Connection:(.+)`, and the second one is `(?m)Connection:(.+)`. As you can see, the only difference is the start-of-line anchor `^`. I thought the former would be faster since it would fail faster. However, my test result reports that the pattern with `^` takes ~0.9ms while the pattern without `^` takes only ~0.1ms. Where is the flaw in my prediction?

The AutoIt version is 3.3.14.2 and I'm using Intel Core 2 CPU.

Comment: You have about 300 uppercase `C` in your content, but over 1000 lines, so there are more places to match `^` than `C`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a pattern starts with a fixed string, a fast algorithm is used to find positions of this string in the subject string before the regex engine starts its normal walk. This way only positions where the pattern may succeed are tested.

Adding the `^` anchor at the start of your pattern disables this optimization. *(the pattern starts no more with a fixed string.)*

That's why sometimes a more *hand-driven* pattern can be slower.